# What domains are covered by AdSense?

Tags: google-adsense

I've had a ton of websites over the years and most of them are collecting tumbleweeds. Many of them have AdSense on them.

I logged into AdSense the other day in an attempt to figure out what domains I am still using. I can't figure out, using their interface, what domains I have setup under that specific Google login.

Is there a way to figure that out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the help for adsense:

> The code generated in your account is
>   valid for any page on any site where
>   you want to display ads. Simply add
>   the code to your page source and we'll
>   automatically detect the new site.

Which means that unless you used authorized domains features (which you probably didn't as it is mostly more convenient not to), you are down to search what you have on the sites for your adsense ID's etc.

You may have added a URL to track into the reports page - under Performance Reports (top bar)->URL Channels, but I do not think these are automatic.

Answer (score 0):

At that time, when you've asked question (2011-01-03 09:19:01Z), I think it wasn't possible, and it was implemented later that year.

Visit your https://www.google.com/adsense dashboard, and in *Performance reports* → *Sites* report, when you switch "Date range" to `24 June 2011–Today`, you can see the list of all sites which made (at least one) ad request with your publisher ID in that period, even if they were not authorised.

About the Sites report: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1407511?hl=en